# Android: Incrementing values in ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have problems with incrementing values in ProgressDialog.

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setTitle("Title");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.setMax(100);
    pd.incrementProgressBy(10);
    pd.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            CallToMyFunction1();
            pd.incrementProgressBy(20);
            CallToMyFunction2();
            pd.incrementProgressBy(60);
            CallToMyFunction3();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }, 100);
}
}
```

I obviously want to start with 10, then after CallToMyFunction1 it should be 30 (10+20), then 90 (10+20+60).
But what I see is that my ProgressDialog shows only 10 and then it disappears.
For some reasons, it ignores "incrementProgressBy" and does not "redraw" values in my ProgressDialog.
Could you help mu understand why?